# How to use Cassandra ODBC driver in delphi?

Tags: delphi, cassandra, odbc

I want to connect to a Cassandra Database from my Delphi application. I found that there is a DataStax OBDC driver. But I didn't found any examples explaining how to connect Cassandra Database from Delphi using ODBC driver.

How to connect Cassandra database from delphi using this ODBC driver?

Comment: have you tried to use the ADO connection wizard? Double click on ADOConnection on form/datamodule and click Build button.

Comment: I tried ADO Connection. But it is very slow.